# How to do cross validation in DistilBERT

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model, distilbert

I have made a simple model to do text classification using DistilBERT. The problem is I am unable to figure out how to do cross-validation while training. My code implementation is provided below.

Can anyone help me to implement cross-validation while training?

Thank you in advance.

```
    #Split into Train-Test-Validation    
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.10, random_state = 0)
    X_val, X_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(X_test,y_test, test_size=0.10, random_state=42)
    
    
    #Encoding text for train data
    train_encoded = tokenizer(X_train, truncation=True, padding=True, return_tensors="tf")
    train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(train_encoded), y_train))
    
    #Encoding text for validation data
    val_encoded = tokenizer(X_val, truncation=True, padding=True, return_tensors="tf")
    val_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(val_encoded), y_val))
    
    #Encoding text for testing data
    test_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(test_encoded), y_test))
    test_encoded = tokenizer(X_test, truncation=True, padding=True, return_tensors="tf")
    
    #Load distil bert model
    model = TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased', num_labels=2)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=model.compute_loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(train_data.batch(16), epochs=10, batch_size=16)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using K-fold validation as a cross-evaluation strategy!

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=99, shuffle=True)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X, y):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    X_val, X_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(X_test,y_test, test_size=0.10, random_state=42)
    #Encoding text for train data
    train_encoded = tokenizer(X_train, truncation=True, padding=True, return_tensors="tf")
    train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(train_encoded), y_train))
    
    #Encoding text for validation data
    val_encoded = tokenizer(X_val, truncation=True, padding=True, return_tensors="tf")
    val_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(val_encoded), y_val))
    
    #Encoding text for testing data
    test_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(test_encoded), y_test))
    test_encoded = tokenizer(X_test, truncation=True, padding=True, return_tensors="tf")
    
    #Load distil bert model
    model = TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased', num_labels=2)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=model.compute_loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(train_data.batch(16), epochs=10, batch_size=16)
    #Get your results and perform analysis
```

As an alternative way, you can wrap your model with sklearn-api support after that enjoy cross-validation and dozens of other utilities offered by sklearn!